# mesos-agent error failed to start: Unsupported container image type: DOCKER

Tags: docker, mesos

I'm running `mesos-master` and `mesos-agent` on the same machine where docker is also installed and running. I'm trying to run a docker app just to see that my Mesos installation is able to run containers but keep getting this error.

**`mesos-execute` log**:

```
I0702 14:18:09.823320 26648 scheduler.cpp:184] Version: 1.3.0
I0702 14:18:09.827054 26644 scheduler.cpp:470] New master detected at master@127.0.0.1:5050
Subscribed with ID d3c94f9d-ff71-48d7-b27f-6b3e0f1e7bd3-0005
Submitted task 'test' to agent 'd3c94f9d-ff71-48d7-b27f-6b3e0f1e7bd3-S0'
Received status update TASK_FAILED for task 'test'
  message: 'Failed to launch container: Unsupported container image type: DOCKER'
  source: SOURCE_AGENT
  reason: REASON_CONTAINER_LAUNCH_FAILED
```

**`mesos-agent` log**:

```
I0702 14:18:09.857992 26541 slave.cpp:1613] Got assigned task 'test' for framework d3c94f9d-ff71-48d7-b27f-6b3e0f1e7bd3-0005
I0702 14:18:09.859424 26541 slave.cpp:1894] Authorizing task 'test' for framework d3c94f9d-ff71-48d7-b27f-6b3e0f1e7bd3-0005
I0702 14:18:09.860486 26541 slave.cpp:2081] Launching task 'test' for framework d3c94f9d-ff71-48d7-b27f-6b3e0f1e7bd3-0005
I0702 14:18:09.861920 26541 paths.cpp:573] Trying to chown '/tmp/mesos/agent/slaves/d3c94f9d-ff71-48d7-b27f-6b3e0f1e7bd3-S0/frameworks/d3c94f9d-ff71-48d7-b27f-6b3e0f1e7bd3-0005/executors/test/runs/9ec3ea4c-a5b3-43c3-9e93-6958093dd0ed' to user 'root'
I0702 14:18:09.862447 26541 slave.cpp:6933] Launching executor 'test' of framework d3c94f9d-ff71-48d7-b27f-6b3e0f1e7bd3-0005 with resources cpus(*)(allocated: *):0.1; mem(*)(allocated: *):32 in work directory '/tmp/mesos/agent/slaves/d3c94f9d-ff71-48d7-b27f-6b3e0f1e7bd3-S0/frameworks/d3c94f9d-ff71-48d7-b27f-6b3e0f1e7bd3-0005/executors/test/runs/9ec3ea4c-a5b3-43c3-9e93-6958093dd0ed'
I0702 14:18:09.863500 26541 slave.cpp:2310] Queued task 'test' for executor 'test' of framework d3c94f9d-ff71-48d7-b27f-6b3e0f1e7bd3-0005
I0702 14:18:09.863682 26541 docker.cpp:1148] Skipping non-docker container
I0702 14:18:09.864451 26545 containerizer.cpp:1001] Starting container 9ec3ea4c-a5b3-43c3-9e93-6958093dd0ed for executor 'test' of framework d3c94f9d-ff71-48d7-b27f-6b3e0f1e7bd3-0005
E0702 14:18:09.866122 26545 slave.cpp:5048] Container '9ec3ea4c-a5b3-43c3-9e93-6958093dd0ed' for executor 'test' of framework d3c94f9d-ff71-48d7-b27f-6b3e0f1e7bd3-0005 failed to start: Unsupported container image type: DOCKER
I0702 14:18:09.866266 26545 containerizer.cpp:2102] Destroying container 9ec3ea4c-a5b3-43c3-9e93-6958093dd0ed in PROVISIONING state
I0702 14:18:09.867729 26530 slave.cpp:5161] Executor 'test' of framework d3c94f9d-ff71-48d7-b27f-6b3e0f1e7bd3-0005 has terminated with unknown status
I0702 14:18:09.868988 26530 slave.cpp:4215] Handling status update TASK_FAILED (UUID: 2b5b5610-86c3-4f4d-ae20-ecac64eabce3) for task test of framework d3c94f9d-ff71-48d7-b27f-6b3e0f1e7bd3-0005 from @0.0.0.0:0
E0702 14:18:09.870321 26530 slave.cpp:4496] Failed to update resources for container 9ec3ea4c-a5b3-43c3-9e93-6958093dd0ed of executor 'test' running task test on status update for terminal task, destroying container: Container not found
W0702 14:18:09.870443 26545 composing.cpp:638] Attempted to destroy unknown container 9ec3ea4c-a5b3-43c3-9e93-6958093dd0ed
I0702 14:18:09.870578 26540 status_update_manager.cpp:323] Received status update TASK_FAILED (UUID: 2b5b5610-86c3-4f4d-ae20-ecac64eabce3) for task test of framework d3c94f9d-ff71-48d7-b27f-6b3e0f1e7bd3-0005
I0702 14:18:09.871279 26533 slave.cpp:4655] Forwarding the update TASK_FAILED (UUID: 2b5b5610-86c3-4f4d-ae20-ecac64eabce3) for task test of framework d3c94f9d-ff71-48d7-b27f-6b3e0f1e7bd3-0005 to master@127.0.0.1:5050
I0702 14:18:09.885476 26540 slave.cpp:3082] Shutting down framework d3c94f9d-ff71-48d7-b27f-6b3e0f1e7bd3-0005
I0702 14:18:09.885699 26540 slave.cpp:5268] Cleaning up executor 'test' of framework d3c94f9d-ff71-48d7-b27f-6b3e0f1e7bd3-0005
I0702 14:18:09.886189 26540 slave.cpp:5356] Cleaning up framework d3c94f9d-ff71-48d7-b27f-6b3e0f1e7bd3-0005
```

I run `mesos-agent` with this command:

```
sudo /home/erezo/mesos/mesos-1.3.0/src/.libs/lt-mesos-agent
--master=127.0.0.1:5050 -zk=zk://127.0.0.1:2181/mesos
--containerizers=docker,mesos --executor_registration_timeout=5mins
--isolation=docker/runtime --work_dir=/tmp/mesos/agent
```

And `mesos-execute` with this:

```
sudo /mesos13/bin/mesos-execute --master=127.0.0.1:5050 --name=test
--docker_image=library/redis --shell=false
```

Could this be permissions(mesos not allowed to run docker) related?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the problem.
The mesos-agent needs to be started with --image_providers=appc,docker.
It was missing and when I add this it works ok. The mesos documentation samples did not include it so I figured it out..